# Degree of faces in a regular graph

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics

Is there any known result on the maximum degree of faces in regular-and-planar graphs ? In particular, is anything known about maximum degree of the faces in a 4-regular planar graph? By degree of a face I mean the number of edges forming it.

Comment: About your definition of "degree": is an edge that is traversed twice on a face counted twice?

Comment: Didn't think of that possibility. But for each face, each edge bounding it, need be counted only once. right ?  Or am I missing something very obvious ?

Comment: Consider a planar embedding of a graph with a cut-edge. That cut-edge will always appear twice in some face-boundary walk.

Comment: OK. Let's count each edge once.

Comment: At least for $d=2,3,4$, there can be arbitrarily large faces. For $d=2$, take really long cycles. For $d=3,4$, it's easier to think in the dual form, i.e., triangulations and quadrangulations with arbitrarily high degree. For example, for $d=3$, take the cone of the wheel graphs.

Comment: For d=3,4 it's easy enough to think in the primal, geometrically: d=3 may be given by a prism over an n-gon, d=4 by an antiprism. d=5 is also possible but doesn't have quite as simple a description (e.g. one way to do it is to take an icosahedron, choose two poles interior to opposite faces, cut it on a longitude line from pole to pole, and glue multiple copies together along their cut lines).

Comment: It appears that you have [crossposted this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/106951/degree-of-faces-in-a-regular-graph) *simultaneously*. Our [site policy](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/231/) only permits a repost after sufficient time has passed and you have not obtained the desired answer elsewhere. Simultaneous crossposting duplicates effort and fractures discussion. I am voting to close;  if your question is still not answered you may request reopening by flagging the question for moderator attention (after summarizing relevant discussions from other sites).

Comment: Thanks for your answer David. I had no idea that I cannot cross-post; I did so thinking it might simply come to more attention simultaneously. Apologies.